# How to setup Python connection to Kafka instance running in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, kafka-python

I am trying to connect to Kafka using Python and I am able to connect and see the topic names however when I try to read messages for any topic nothing happens. It feels like the connection times-out as python does not throw an error.

I am port-forwarding to Kafka and then using localhost:{port} as my bootstrap_server.

I do not have experience working with Kubernetes, Kafka or anything networking or cloud related and the person who set-up our system up has left the company.

I am using the kafka-python package (version 2.0.2) and python 3.9.
The simple code below (basically copied from the docs) is being run within Pycharm, no docker container.

```
from kafka import KafkaConsumer
consumer = KafkaConsumer('my-topic', bootstrap_servers='localhost:10523')
# this works
topics = list(consumer.topics())
# this does not work
for msg in consumer:
    print(msg)
```

The Kafka topic already contains ~10,000 messages that I thought should by printed by the code above. I have also tried using `auto_offset_reset='earliest'` but that also does not work.

When the Kafka messages do not print my port-forward does throw this error (after I close my python console),
E0420 20:36:09.333793   26252 portforward.go:385] error copying from local connection to remote stream: read tcp6 [::1]:10523->[::1]:123456: wsarecv: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

Is there something wrong with the Kafka setup? How could I check this?
How could I debug to locate the actual issue?
Should I be port-forwarding to connect or is there a better way to connect using my local machine?

Comment: See linked duplicate post. Even though you are using kubernetes, same answer applies. A "port forward" does not work in kafka the way you expect it to. You need to configure the actual Pod/Service/Ingress, etc of the Kafka container and k8s cluster as well. Also read https://strimzi.io/blog/2019/04/17/accessing-kafka-part-1/ (and, yes, the "better way" is to use an Ingress, ideally via Strimzi, if you are not using it)

Comment: Hi. Thanks for sending that across and the clarification. I will try that approach.